# ClickListener in cardview return null exception

Tags: android

I have some problem when I try to click a cardview, I want it to make toast with its ID. But whenever I click the cardview, it always crashed and get null exception on its listener. already declare the listener but still crashed. Thank You

Listener class

```
public interface ResetPasswordListener {
    void onClickCardview(String userid);
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class ResetPasswordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResetPasswordAdapter.ViewHolder> implements ResetPasswordListener {

    private List<ResetPasswordRespModel> resetList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ResetPasswordListener resetPasswordListener;

    public void setOnClick(ResetPasswordListener listener) {
        this.resetPasswordListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickCardview(String userid) {
        Log.d("ID VALUE", userid);
        resetPasswordListener.onClickCardview(userid);
    }
}
```

This is how I set the listener in fragment class

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listResetPasswordBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.list_reset_password, container, false);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reset_password, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        listResetPasswordBinding.setOnClick(new ResetPasswordListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickCardview(String userid) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), userid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Error Logs

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void example.com.absensiapp.view.listener.ResetPasswordListener.onClickCardview(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at example.com.absensiapp.view.adapter.ResetPasswordAdapter.onClickCardview(ResetPasswordAdapter.java:35)
    at example.com.absensiapp.databinding.ListResetPasswordBindingImpl._internalCallbackOnClick(ListResetPasswordBindingImpl.java:227)
    at example.com.absensiapp.generated.callback.OnClickListener.onClick(OnClickListener.java:11)
```

Comment: Logs of your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be `onCreateView` you are inflating the layout twice one with `DataBindingUtil.inflate` adn once with `inflater.inflate`. Modify it

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listResetPasswordBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.list_reset_password, container, false);
    return listResetPasswordBinding.getroot();
}
```

Also call `setOnClick` of  `ResetPasswordAdapter` to set listener. Until you set the listener you will keep getting a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you! I use `listBinding.setOnClick` to set the listener before, try to change it to  `adapter.setOnClick` and it works.